# No audio output to HDMI using MPV but using OMXplayer works fine?

Tags: audio

I am trying to use MPV to play a video stream to my HDMI tv. Video works well, but there's no audio regardless of what I set the `--audio-device=` to. OMXplayer however works just fine both as default and with using `-o hdmi`.

I am currently working on using pulseaudio but haven't had any success yet.

Here is the result of `aplay -l`:

```
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Loopback [Loopback], device 0: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 0: Loopback [Loopback], device 1: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
```

and `aplay -L`:

```
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
sysdefault:CARD=Loopback
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Loopback
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Default Audio Device
surround21:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
dmix:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Loopback,DEV=1
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Loopback,DEV=1
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Loopback,DEV=1
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Loopback,DEV=1
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

Answer (score 2):

List mpv help for "--audio-device=" parameter:

```
mpv --audio-device=help
```

Simple incanatation of mpv playing audio through a specified HDMI audio device, substitute URL for your url or media file:

```
mpv --audio-device='alsa/hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1' URL
```

Similar to the last incanatation of mpv, but playing the video on a secondary screen:

```
DISPLAY=:0.1 mpv --audio-device='alsa/hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1' --fullscreen URL
```